# Regex not returning consistent results

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an array of a sliced up sentence `split`, but the regex I test against each 'word' does not seem to be consistent.

```
function test (reg) {
  const tags = [];
  const split = ["man", "man"];

  console.log(split)
  split.forEach((word, key) => {
    console.log(key)
    if (reg.test(word)) {
      console.info('Word:', word)
      tags.push(word)
    } else {
      console.log('Not word:', word)
    }
  })
}

const pathRegex = new RegExp(/^[A-ZÀ-Ýa-zà-ý0-9_]+[^.#$?\[\]]$/g);
const pathRegex2 = new RegExp(/^[0-9a-zA-Z/-]+[^.#$?\[\]]$/g);

console.log('test 1:')
test(pathRegex)
console.log('test 2:')
test(pathRegex2)
```

See: https://codepen.io/TrySpace/pen/VwZNPLV?editors=1112

The output:

```
0
Word: man
1
Not word: man
```

What am I missing here?

I would expect the `RegExp.test` to return the same result each time.

What I did notice is when I replace `reg` with `new RegExp(/^[A-ZÀ-Ýa-zà-ý0-9_]+[^.#$?\[\]]$/g)` it will give me the expected  result.

The question is why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your notice is correct. The problem that regular expressions with the `g` modifier will keep track of the `lastIndex` where a match occurred.
So we can say that they are stateful in that case.

You can pass a string expression and create a `RegExp` object in your function.

Or apply a `dirty hack` and reset `lastIndex` manually:

```
reg.lastIndex = 0;
```

Comment: You beat me for seconds, +1

Comment: clear and concise  +1